# What is the filter to get a heavy metal film ilustration?

Tags: filters

How I can transform an image to get a same image style like the Heavy Metal film?.

[image]

I remember that I could read a paper about this, but I lost it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two techniques that can achieve similar results, but if you caught that in a recent paper then you are probably after [Style Transfer](https://github.com/lengstrom/fast-style-transfer/).

It is based on "teaching" a neural network how to combine specific elementary features in one context (e.g. Renaissance paintings) and then applying them in a different context (e.g. some random picture).

The other technique is "Colour Transfer" (or "image re-colouring") and that one attempts to copy just the colour tones and overall "feel" from one image to another but without changing the structure of its content. [Here](https://people.cs.clemson.edu/~dhouse/papers/02palette-techreport.pdf) is a good overview and a particular method of applying it.

Hope this helps.